# Code to convert .XLSX spreadsheet to CSV is not working as expected

Tags: excel, perl, csv

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a number of columns and rows. I want to turn this into a CSV, but only include certain columns in the CSV.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX -> new();
my $workbook = $excel->parse('headers.xlsx');
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);
my $destination = 'csv.txt';
my $csv;
my ($row_min, $row_max) = $worksheet->row_range();
my ($col_min, $col_max) = $worksheet->col_range();

for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

        # my $cell = $worksheet>{Cells}[$row][$col];
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
        if ($cell) {
            if ($col eq ( 'A' || 'S' || 'T' || 'AA' || 'AX' || 'BC' || 'D' || 'AN' || 'AV' )) {
                if ($col == $col_max) {
                    $csv .= $cell->Value . "\n";
                    } else {
                    $csv .= $cell->Value . ",";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

open (my $fh, '>', $destination) or die '$! error trying to write';
print $fh $csv;
close ($fh);
```

I don't get any errors or warnings when I run it, which doesn't help to identify the problem.

Can anyone identify any errors?

Comment: `Text::CSV` is worth looking at. One possible cause of 'no input; no errors' is if the loops never iterate - what values do you have for `$row_min` etc.?

Comment: Oops - I had accidentally overwritten the excel on a previous experiment. Restored the contents now. With my code above, I am getting an error
"Use of uninitialized value $csv in print at ProtonToJSON.pl line 36."

Do I need to declare this as a global variable?

Comment: No, you already did that. It's uninitialized though, which means nothing has been assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test

```
$col eq ( 'A' || 'S' || 'T' || 'AA' || 'AX' || 'BC' || 'D' || 'AN' || 'AV' )
```

is finding the first of those text strings that is *true*, which is `A`, and comparing that with `$col`, which isn't what you want at all. You would have to write

```
$col eq 'A' || $col eq 'S' || $col eq 'T' || $col eq 'AA' || $col eq 'AX' || $col eq 'BC' || $col eq 'D' || $col eq 'AN' || $col eq 'AV'
```

except that the module doesn't deal in column labels like that so you need to transform them to numbers

I've written this, which should work. It first builds a hash which relates each column label to its number for the first 100 columns. Then I've used that hash to convert your list of labels to a list of column numbers, and iterated over that. (It produces `[1, 4, 19, 20, 27, 40, 48, 50, 55]` if you're interested.) It's much neater than iterating over *all* the columns and ignoring the ones you don't want

It's not tested as I don't have a data file to test with, but it does compile

I'm not at all sure about your code that skips a cell if it contains a *false* value. That is going to skip empty cells and cells containing the number zero, and it will leave the columns in your CSV file misaligned as a result. The part of my code that does that is `@csv_row = grep $_, @csv_row` and you may want to remove that if you agree with me

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;

my ($source, $dest) = qw/ headers.xlsx headers.csv /;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new;
my $workbook = $excel->parse($source);
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);
my ($row_min, $row_max) = $worksheet->row_range;

my %col_numbers;
for ( my ($n, $name) = (1, 'A'); $n <= 100; ++$n, ++$name ) {
    $col_numbers{$name} = $n;
}

my @cols = sort { $a <=> $b }
        map $col_numbers{$_}, qw/ A  S  T  AA  AX  BC  D  AN  AV /;

open my $fh, '>', $dest
        or die qq{Unable to open "$dest" for output: $!};

for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
    my @csv_row = map $worksheet->get_cell($row, $_)->unformatted, @cols;
    print $fh join(',', @csv_row), "\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks for your update Borodin. I tested your code but unfortunately the csv file contains weird hash references like: 
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH
(0x2d575d0),Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH
(0x2d57870),Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH
(0x2d616c8),Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH


You're right about the skipping a cell if it contains false. I don't want to do this.

Comment: @Jamie:  Okay, I wasn't aware that the `get_cell` method returned an object, and I can't test this. I've made a correction; please test it now

Answer (score 2):

First, $col is numeric, so you shouldn't be testing it against string column names.

Second, you need e.g.

```
$col==7 || $col==9 ||...
```

As you have it, it is only testing $col eq 'A' (since that is the result of all the ||'s).